# On MongoDB how can I limit the query, when my callback is inside "find"?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this query in MongoDB

```
db.privateMessages.find( 
    { $or : [ 
       {fromId: userId, toId: socket.userId} , 
       {fromId: socket.userId, toId: userId} ] 
    }, 
    function(err, messages) { pushSvdMsgs(messages); });
```

It works perfectly, except for the fact that I get 50 results.

I have tried this:

```
db.privateMessages.find( { $or : [ {fromId: userId, toId: socket.userId} , {fromId: socket.userId, toId: userId} ] }, function(err, messages) { pushSvdMsgs(messages); }).limit(10);
```

But that didn't help either, so I tried this below which also didn't help limit it.

```
db.privateMessages.find( { $or : [ {fromId: userId, toId: socket.userId} , {fromId: socket.userId, toId: userId} ] }, { $limit : 2 }, function(err, messages) { pushSvdMsgs(messages); });
```

How can I limit the number of results from this query, and still call the callback the same way I have?

Comment: So, are you getting more than 50 documents and you want only 50?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Almost, I quickly saw a code here which worked very nicely, it was this:


        db.privateMessages.find( { $or : [ {fromId: userId, toId: socket.userId} ,
                {fromId: socket.userId, toId: userId} ] },
            {},
            { limit : 10 },
            function(err, messages) { pushSvdMsgs(messages); });


But from now, there are 2 things I wonder, why is there a empty {}, is that where I put how to order it, because I would also like to order it by "timeStamp" DESC

Comment: Ok, if it works for you, then I'll undelete my answer so that you can accept it. I don't work with node.js, so I wasn't sure if I googled it right :)

Apparently, the syntax is (query, fields, options). So we need that empty `{}` to put options in their place.

Comment: What driver are you using? Mongodb-native?

Comment: Ah, so "order by" is probably within the same {} as limit then. 
If by "driver" you mean how I communicate with MongoDB from Node.js (my apologies, my knowledge on terminologies is horrible, hehe), then I use "mongojs". I tried Mongoose before but did not have much luck getting it to work.
Thank you for the help, and undelete your answer and I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You got it almost right. Try this one:

```
db.privateMessages.find( { $or : [ {fromId: userId, toId: socket.userId} , 
                                   {fromId: socket.userId, toId: userId} ] },
                         {}, 
                         { limit : 2 }, 
                         function(err, messages) { pushSvdMsgs(messages); });
```

The syntax is `find(query, fields, options)`. We need that empty object to make driver interpret options correctly.

Comment: That "empty object" is for excluding specific fields from been returned in your result set.