# db.collection.find() is ignoring query criteria

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following node.js code interacting with mongo:

```
var lowrange = 1;
var collection = db.get('postings');
collection.find({},{postid: { $gt: lowrange }, limit: 10, sort: {_id: -1}},function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
});
```

I am using this to list the contents of the collection 'postings' via a json response. The limit: 10 and sort criteria work as expected. The postid: { $gt: lowrange } section seems to be ignored.
In other words, I am getting all records, even those that are less than the var lowrange. Why is this?

Edit:

Then what is the correct syntax? This produces no results (I assure you there are documents with a post id greater than 1):

```
collection.find({postid: { $gt: 1 }}, function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
});
```

and how do you use limit/sort when you have a function as a param of find? The following errors:

```
collection.find({postid: { $gt: 1 }}, function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
}).limit(10).sort( {_id: -1});
```

Comment: If i am not wrong you have not specified any condition, you wrote find({},) the first object decidess which record to give... The second object tells which fields to give..

Comment: As mentioned by @Modi ..you have given condition like find({}).It will match all the docs.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of `find` is the query document. Yours is empty (`{}`).

In fact, I'm not sure where you've seen that syntax, with `limit` and `sort` as field names.

See [Read Operations Overview](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/).

Comment: Oddly that syntax works. I've read the link you provided- thank you. However it doesn't seem like I can tack on .sort() and other modifiers after find() if I have a function inside the find params.

Comment: If you find a link to your syntax, I'd appreciate you adding a comment here. I'm a bit new to MongoDB myself. Maybe it's specific to Node.js?

Comment: So googling I found a few examples of this syntax: http://code.runnable.com/UW3vaGTkq498AACC/query-for-records-in-mongodb-using-mongodb-native-for-node-js  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970443/on-mongodb-how-can-i-limit-the-query-when-my-callback-is-inside-find. The second one seems to imply you can make a 3rd parameter- which I haven't seen else ware. Regardless, it still doesn't seem to listen to my $gt query even if I put it in the first param.

Comment: I think this syntax may be specific to the Node.js driver. See http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#find. Maybe it's from the earlier version, as well.